# z value for output in async reset register - verilog

Tags: verilog

i want to make a register with synce load and asynce reset 
it's my module

```
module register32bit(indata,load,reset,clk,outdate);
input [31:0]indata;
input load;
input clk;
input reset;
output [31:0] outdate;
wire [31:0] indata;
reg [31:0] outdata;
wire clk;
wire load;
wire reset;

always @(posedge clk or reset) begin
if(reset) begin  
 outdata <= 0;
end
else if(load) begin
 outdata <= indata;
end
end
endmodule
```

now the problem is in my tb
how can i test the module???
here's my tb 

i dont know why the outdate haz 'z' value and dont know that this way of using tb is logical or not

```
module tb1();
reg [31:0]indata;
reg load;
reg clk = 0;
reg reset;
wire [31:0]outdata;
initial begin
#0 indata = 32'haef27c80;
#10 load = 1;
#3 clk = 1;
#0 clk = 0;
#10 $finish;
end

register32bit reg32b(
.indata(indata),
.load(load),
.reset(reset),
.clk(clk),
.outdate(outdate)
);

initial begin
$monitor("indata:%b\nclk:%b\nload:%b\nreset:%b\noutdata:%b\n------------",
indata,clk,load,reset,outdate,);
end
endmodule
```

and this is the result

```
# indata:10101110111100100111110010000000
# clk:0
# load:x
# reset:x
# outdata:z
# ------------ 
# indata:10101110111100100111110010000000
# clk:0
# load:1
# reset:x
# outdata:z
# ------------ 
# indata:10101110111100100111110010000000
# clk:0
# load:1
# reset:x
# outdata:zhere
```

please make a tb for me and if the register module has some problems , tell them to me
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not driving your output `outdata` in module `register32bit`. You're not driving the wire `outdata` in your testbench. This is presumably because the typo `outdate` appears throughout your code.

Comment: Correct the typos and take it from there. If you have another problem, ask another question.

Comment: no , this is the problem , but how can i do correct the typos?
would you plz give me a sample? or correct the code?

Comment: OP still doesn't understand so I'll try my best.

In your module `register32bit` you have an output `[31:0] outdate;`. But it's never been assigned any value. In `always` process you only assign value to `[31:0] outdata`. That's why [Matthew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5900011/matthew-taylor) suggested a typo in your code. You can either change the output `outdate` to `outdata` to make a `output reg [31:0] outdata` or use `assign` statement to "glue" those two variables together.

Comment: omg, now i got it , srr , my english is not so good and the verilog is my universty project , thanks a lot botu MatthewTaylor and dear Raz

Comment: @Shahab.es , I suggest you learned about ANSI style module headers. It will make your code more concise and make typos easier to identify them the legacy style you are currently using.